# An FB Contact name not displaying while calling, Only number shows up

Tags: contacts, facebook, caller-id

I have a couple of contacts in my Samsung Galaxy S i9003 which runs Android 2.3.6, which are retrieved from my FB contact list. That means, those names and contact numbers are not saved in my SIM/Phone, they are only in FB. Since I have synchronized FB account, I can see those contacts from my contact-list. Whenever I call them or they call me, their names are not showing up and only numbers as if they are not in my contact list (And I don't have a clue on who is calling). But if I check my call logs later, I can see their number along with their name.

I want to see their names while they are calling. How do I do it in my case? Thanks a lot for your help.